# Php store hours- setup

Tags: php, wordpress

Have been trying to set up some php script below without any luck and would appreciate some help on how to set it up. Which file(s) to copy and where to put them is my main problem right now so please help out if you can. Thanks

https://github.com/coryetzkorn/php-store-hours

Answer (score 0):

Just download the file `StoreHours.class.php` form github and include this file in your file where you want to show store hours..

```
include('StoreHours.class.php');
```

Now set the `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`

Define daily open hours

```
// Must be in 24-hour format, separated by dash
// If closed for the day, leave blank (ex. sunday)
// If open multiple times in one day, enter time ranges separated by a comma

$hours = array(
        'mon' => array('11:00-20:30'),
        'tue' => array('11:00-13:00', '18:00-20:30'),
        'wed' => array('11:00-20:30'),
        'thu' => array('11:00-1:30'), // Open late
        'fri' => array('11:00-20:30'),
        'sat' => array('11:00-20:00'),
        'sun' => array() // Closed all day
);
```

Add exceptions days (optional)

```
// Add exceptions (great for holidays etc.)
// MUST be in a format month/day[/year] or [year-]month-day
// Do not include the year if the exception repeats annually
$exceptions = array(
    '2/24'  => array('11:00-18:00'),
    '10/18' => array('11:00-16:00', '18:00-20:30')
);
```

Set templates messages to be show

```
// Place HTML for output below. This is what will show in the browser.
// Use {%hours%} shortcode to add dynamic times to your open or closed message.
$template = array(
    'open'           => "Yes, we're open! Today's hours are {%hours%}.",
    'closed'         => "Sorry, we're closed. Today's hours are {%hours%}.",
    'closed_all_day' => "Sorry, we're closed today.",
    'separator'      => " - ",
    'join'           => " and ",
    'format'         => "g:ia", // options listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
    'hours'          => "{%open%}{%separator%}{%closed%}"
);
```

Initiate class store hours

```
$store_hours = new StoreHours($hours, $exceptions, $template);
```

Call render method to output open / closed message

```
$store_hours->render();
```

Display full list of open hours (for a week)

```
echo '<table>';
    foreach ($store_hours->hours_this_week() as $days => $hours) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $days . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $hours . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

That's it.... :)

Comment: Thanks will try set it up now.